# Showing the total of a column without repeating values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a script which outputs a csv with five columns. I've added two lines of code to SUM two of those columns. I have managed to do this, however, the totals are these columns are repeated on every row, where i just want the totals to be shown on one row.

```
df['Unit Total'] = df['Units Sold'].sum()
df['Total Revenue'] = df['data_revenue'].sum()
```

This is what my script produces

```
8   0.013207    AR  ARS 0.105656    74012   575.2779
10  0.013207    AR  ARS 0.13207     74012   575.2779
6   0.013207    AR  ARS 0.079242    74012   575.2779
6   0.013207    AR  ARS 0.079242    74012   575.2779
```

What i actually want to see

```
8   0.013207    AR  ARS 0.105656    74012   575.2779
10  0.013207    AR  ARS 0.13207     
6   0.013207    AR  ARS 0.079242    
6   0.013207    AR  ARS 0.079242
```

My Script

```
for filename in filelist:
    print(filename)
    df = pandas.read_csv('SYB_M_20171001_20171031.txt', header=None, encoding='utf-8', sep='\t', names=colnames,
                         skiprows=3, usecols=['Units Sold', 'Dealer Price', 'End Consumer Country', 'Currency Code']
                         )
    df['data_revenue'] = df['Units Sold'] * df['Dealer Price']
    df = df.sort_values(['End Consumer Country', 'Currency Code'])
    df['Unit Total'] = df['Units Sold'].sum()
    df['Total Revenue'] = df['data_revenue'].sum()
    df.to_csv(outfile + r"\output.csv", index=None)
    dflist.append(filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set first value of index by position:

```
df.loc[df.index[0], 'Unit Total'] = df['Units Sold'].sum()

df.loc[df.index[0], 'Unit Revenue'] = df['data_revenue'].sum()
```

Another solution is create default index by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`, so possible set by `0`:

```
df = df.sort_values(['End Consumer Country', 'Currency Code']).reset_index(drop=True)

df.loc[0, 'Unit Total'] = df['Units Sold'].sum()
df.loc[0, 'Unit Revenue'] = df['data_revenue'].sum()
```

Comment: I'm getting an attribute error 'AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get_loc''

Comment: Thank you for the edit, but i'm still getting an error. This time 'KeyError: 'Unit Total'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187267/discussion-between-james-upson-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
df.loc[0,'Unit Total']=df['Units Sold'].sum()
df.loc[0,'Total Revenue']=df['data_revenue'].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign with a single [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) call:

```
label_positions = list(map(df.columns.get_loc, ['Unit Total', 'data_revenue']))
df.iloc[0, label_positions] = df[['Units Sold', 'data_revenue']].sum().values
```